# How can I set the TestNG option "configfailurepolicy" via Maven in the POM?

Tags: java, maven, testng, pom.xml

TestNG has an option called -configfailurepolicy that you can specify on the command line, or you can specify it in the suite XML file (if you are using one.)

I would like to set that via Maven in the POM, but there is no documentation I can find anywhere that explains how to do that. Can I, and if so, what do I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a ticket from 2012 on this: https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SUREFIRE-927

Supposedly, it was fixed. Based on pull request and release dates, it should be an available option in any release including or after 2.13. Looks like the maven default right now is 2.12.4, so you'll have to manually configure the surefire plugin to a working version.

Once you have the latest version, you should be able to pass in `-Dconfigfailurepolicy=continue` on the commandline, or configure it in the xml

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.13</version>
      <configuration>
        <configfailurepolicy>continue</configfailurepolicy>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

I had the same issue and this fixed it for me.

Comment: It turns out you cannot use that option with Failsafe, just with Surefire. I'm using Failsafe since I'm only performing integration tests. However, your answer shows that the option really does work as long as I put it in the right place, and with Surefire. Thanks!

Comment: @thekevinmonster It surely is possible through Failsafe - see my answer below and consider marking it is the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

`configfailurepolicy` **IS** configurable though Failsafe with the versions of Failsafe and TestNG available at the time of asking.

This configuration worked with TestNG 6.8.8 and Failsafe 2.17.

`<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.17</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>integration-test</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <properties>
                    <property>
                        <name>configfailurepolicy</name>
                        <value>continue</value>
                    </property>
                </properties>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>`

The resulting `Reporter` output was

```
2016-08-23 08:02:18.367  SampleTest           Starting Test
2016-08-23 08:02:18.378  SampleTest           sampleTest--Test Skipped

2016-08-22 20:02:18.632  SampleTest1          Starting Test
2016-08-22 20:02:18.633  SampleTest1          sampleTest1--Test Pass

2016-08-22 20:02:18.738  SampleTest2          Starting Test
2016-08-22 20:02:18.738  SampleTest2          sampleTest2--Test Pass
```

As an aside, getting configuration into TestNG via Failsafe when not explicitly catered for through the plugin API is not documented anywhere as far as I can tell - I got to this through trial and error. I suspect this method will work for other [command line arguments](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#running-testng) that are not explicitly supported through Failsafes API .